# Page reloading while dispatching a form data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to submit a form data to the reducer via action creators but its not working anyway.The page is reloading anyway.I can't resist.

Below is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {addName} from '../Actions/actionCreators'
class about extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2> About me </h2>

                <form action="" onSubmit={this.submitform}>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        submitform : (e) => {
            dispatch(addName(e.target.name.value))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(about)
```

Here `addName` is the action creator which receives data(name)

if i am using this,also error happens 'this.props.dispatch` is not a function

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.submithandle = this.submithandle.bind(this)
}
submithandle(e, dispatch){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.dispatch(addName(e.target.name.value))
}
```

What step i can take to submit data via `mapDispatchToProps`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand mapDispatchToProps correctly. mapDispatchToProps will add the functions to the delivered props of the component. The props of about looks like this:

```
{submitform: (e) => {dispatch(addName(e.target.name.value))}}
```

To call the submitform prop, you have to access it with this.props.submitform.
If you write that into your onSubmit prop of form, it should work.
You should also set the names of your react components to start with an upper-case so that react can differentiate them between native and new components. So about => About.
Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need a handler for the onSubmit event.

```
this.handleSubmit(e)=>{
  this.props.addNameAction(e.target.value);
}
```

then Dispatch the action that you supposedly imported at the top.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return{
    addNameAction : (name) => {
        dispatch(addName(name))
    }
}
```

}